# Drive REST API not giving more than 100 results

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried the Drive REST api to get my shared files.
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=sharedWithMe%3Dtrue

I am unable to get more than 100 results. I am using authorization: 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to copy and paste the same response I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42831062/7720472).

I'm facing the same problem so I've been doing some tests and this is what I've found:

- If I try files.list with fields: "files, nextPageToken", I get 100 files only.
- If I try files.list with fields: "files(name, id, *etc*, **parents**), nextPageToken", I get 460 files.
- If I try files.list with fields: "files(name, id, *etc*), nextPageToken" **without parents field**, I get 1000 files.
- If I try files.list with fields: "files(parents), nextPageToken", I get 460 files.

So it seems that depends on how many fields you request and also if one of the fields requested is parents field.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that you need to monitor nextPageToken and keep fetching results until nextPageToken is undefined/null

Answer (score 0):

That's the default amount of results. You need to provide the `maxResults` query parameter.

[Drive REST API doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) - did you even look at it?

Comment: yes I tried with maxResults=1000 but still I got 100 results though I had more than 100 files.

Comment: this answer,and the answer from @adjuremods are incorrect. Increasing maxResults (to say 1000) is NOT guaranteed to return 1000 results. It is "maxResults" not "numResults" so it's only a maximum. Drive could happily return 0 results in the first tranche.

Comment: Obviously you can't query more results/files than actually exist. He clearly stated in his question he **has** > 100 files and in that case **maxResults** is what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

As @rorschach stated, you need to use [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) query parameter.

> Maximum number of files to return. Acceptable values are 0 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)

As stated in this [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/), you can set the the number of records returned per page up to 1000 by setting `MaxResults`. Make sure that you configured it properly. Here is a sample code:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.MaxResults = 1000;
FileList files = request.Execute();
```

But if you have more then 1000 files and directories on your Google Drive, then you need to use `Nextpage`. You can check the sample code in the tutorial provided above.

Edit: if using API v3, the property is `PageSize` rather than `MaxResults` referred to in the above tutorial. Setting the page token is the same.

Answer (score 0):

My code for that full example:

```
//  This requires the Drive API To be turned on in the Advanced Google Services
function countFilesInFolder() {
  var folderid = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("html").next().getId();
  var query = 'trashed = false and "' + folderid + '"' + " in parents and title contains 'json'"// mimeType ="application/json"';
  var pageToken = null;

  var filesInFolder = Drive.Files.list({
    q: query,
    maxResults: 1000,
    pageSize: 1000,
    pageToken: pageToken,
  });
  pageToken = filesInFolder.nextPageToken;
  var cards = filesInFolder.items.length;
  while (pageToken != null) {
    filesInFolder = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 1000,
      pageSize: 1000,
      pageToken: pageToken,
    });
    cards = cards + filesInFolder.items.length;
    pageToken = filesInFolder.nextPageToken;
  }
  Logger.log("filesInFolder: " + cards);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding an explanation of how and why they work.