# List request page size being ignored

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been working with the drive SDK for the last few days and previously I was able to request 1000 items on a page using listrequest. Now I'm only getting 100 files no matter how high I set the parameter, but if I set it below 100 it will return whatever number. Did they decide to change the max results overnight or something?

Answer (score 9):

I'm facing the same problem so I've been doing some tests and this is what I've found:

- If I try files.list with fields: "files, nextPageToken", I get 100 files only.
- If I try files.list with fields: "files(name, id, *etc*, **parents**), nextPageToken", I get 460 files.
- If I try files.list with fields: "files(name, id, *etc*), nextPageToken" **without parents field**, I get 1000 files.
- If I try files.list with fields: "files(parents), nextPageToken", I get 460 files.

So it seems that depends on how many fields you request and also if one of the fields requested is parents field.

Comment: This is still the same. I get 460 files when I request with 'parents'. Drive api docs doesn't have this mentioned anywhere.

Comment: FWIW: requesting field "permissions" always limit to 100 files, whereas requesting "permissionIds"  can return up to 1000 files.

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood what pagesize does. It is a maximum value, not an absolute value. You should always iterate list results until nextPageToken is null.