# Google Drive Files:list API for jumbo account?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm using the Drive files: list API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to list the file permissions on a truly jumbo account, and it's taking forever (currently 28M files after running for nearly a week). Anyone have any tips or tricks for doing this any faster?

I know how to use multiprocessing/multithreading to process a bunch of accounts in parallel, but I'm stumped in terms of speeding up any one single account.

I'm using python3 if it makes a difference, though it seems like the slowness is largely due to the fact that it takes a couple of seconds for the Google APIs to return each batch of 100 files.

Editing to add what I'm currently doing that takes a lot of time (this is a snippet from a larger script, but captures the essential parts):

```
items_count=0
while True:
    if items_count>0: log(logging.DEBUG,curr_user+": Getting next set of items. Items so far: "+str(items_count))
    results=gw_list_files_page(service,curr_user,nextPageToken)

    if results==None:
        log(logging.ERROR,curr_user+": error when listing files")
        return

    nextPageToken=results.get('nextPageToken')
    
    if not nextPageToken:
        break


def gw_list_files_page(service,curr_user,nextPageToken):
    # Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425646/the-pagesize-parameter-does-not-work-in-google-drive-api-v3, even though we're setting pageSize to be 1000, we can only get 100 at a time:
    # "For instance, including permissions in the files fields will limit the set to 100 each, while including parents will limit it to 360 items each."

    results=None
    
    if nextPageToken:
        results = service.files().list(pageToken=str(nextPageToken), pageSize=1000, q="'"+curr_user+"' in owners", fields="nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,files(mimeType,parents,shared,permissions(type,emailAddress,role,deleted),id,name)").execute()
    else:
        results = service.files().list(pageSize=1000, q="'"+curr_user+"' in owners", fields="nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,files(mimeType,parents,shared,permissions(type,emailAddress,role,deleted),id,name)").execute()
    
    return results
```

Comment: I would like to share about this guide on improving performance on google drive: [Improve Performance](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance), have you seen this? Can you also provide the code that you are working on so I can better understand your concern?

Comment: Thanks @Twilight! I have seen that guide--I'm already just requesting the fields I need. I've just added some sample code above to show more precisely what I'm doing.